# How to Embed/Wrap the VB Script into Exe and Extract during the run time

Tags: vbscript

I would like to convert the VB Script ( .VBS file) into EXE. If any one has any idea on how to convert VBS to Exe, Please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Some VBS IDEs allow this by default ([vbsedit](http://www.vbsedit.com/) is one example) and there are also lots of tools that would do the conversion I even [found a web page for that purpose](http://www.vbs2exe.com/). The list is quite long, if you google vbs to exe you will find many more.

Please keep in mind that this is not a compilation. Most will either pack the scripting host and the exe together or even just be the vbs file in a self extracting archive (you could also do this yourself with 7zip e.g.) This means the code will probably still be easily obtainable so it is not save to use this with cleartext passwords.

I also found [this tool](http://www.abyssmedia.com/vbstoexe.shtml) which claims to encrypt/obfuscate  the script, but I cannot say how secure it really would be.

As a side note: If you encrypt the script any error message will be with the completely wrong line number, which confused some people I know who used these methods. So for debugging always use the original script.